# Jsoup Parsing After Login

Tags: java, php, android, parsing, jsoup

I would like to parse a web page, however after doing authentication (login into practice), to make the step authentication parameters at the login page, then after I'm going to load it with a webview. The login works perfectly, once logged in, I would like to parse a page, so I pass the URL of the page you want, but he returns the login page, as if I did not access.

I tried searching everywhere but I did not understand, everyone does it differently, if you can help me I shall be very grateful.
Thanks a lot in advance
See you soon

Comment: Could you give more information of the website you need to log-in and extract information ? Is it a public URL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String url ="indirizzo"+ MainActivity.codschool.getText().toString()+"&login="+MainActivity.id.getText().toString()+"&password="+MainActivity.pw.getText().toString();
            Connection.Response res = Jsoup
                    .connect("url")

                    .data("login", MainActivity.id.getText().toString())
                    .data("password",MainActivity.pw.getText().toString())
                    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                    .execute();

            //Keep logged in
            Map<String, String> cookies = res.cookies();
```